# why type casting doesn't work in here?

Tags: c++, casting

The following code has type casting error

```
#define IMG_I (std::complex<double>(0, 1))
#define PI 3.1415926535
for (unsigned long int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
  std::cout << exp(-IMG_I * PI * j);
```

The type casting can be easily solved by using extra parenthesis or changing the order of multiplication. But it is not clear for me why the type casting problem occurs in the first place and why the c++ cannot handle the above code as it is.

can anyone explain this for me?

Comment: How about putting in the error you're getting.  I suspect the compiler may have issues with '-(std::complex<double>(0, 1))', but it's hard to say without an error message

Comment: Why not just use a `const std::complex<double> IMG_I(0, 1);`?

Comment: Your macros are hiding some of your implicit casting to incompatible types ...

Comment: What are you talking about? There is no type-casting in this code.

Comment: @rob-kennedy take it easy Rob

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This `operator*` overload for `std::complex` is a function template with a declaration that looks like:

```
template<typename T> 
complex<T> operator*(const complex<T>& lhs, const T& val);
```

The `T` in `complex<T>` for the `lhs` argument must be the same as the `T` for the `val` argument in order for template argument deduction to work.

You are trying to call it with a `std::complex<double>` (the type of `-IMG_I * PI`) and an `unsigned long` (the type of `j`).  `double` and `unsigned long` are not the same type, so template argument deduction fails.

`-IMG_I * (PI * j)` works because the type of `PI * j` is `double`, so there is no ambiguity as to what `T` is.  Likewise, `-IMG_I * PI * static_cast<double>(j)` works for the same reason.

Comment: wish I could give +2 for `static_cast<double>(j)`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the header file defining complex:

`template

    inline complex<_Tp>

    operator*(const complex<_Tp>& __x, const _Tp& __y)

    {

      complex<_Tp> __r = __x;

      __r *= __y;

      return __r;

    }`

You'll see that instead of accepting a `_Tp` (in this case a double), the second parameter is a `const _Tp&`. This means that C++ is unwilling to perform the implicit cast from the integer `j`, hence the error.

If the second parameter were rewritten as a `_Tp`, C++'s built-in implicit type conversion would cast the integer to a double, and your code would compile.

Comment: This is incorrect:  if we didn't have the argument deduction failure (say, if the parameters were of type `complex<T>` and `U`), a temporary `double` would be created from the `unsigned long` and that temporary could be passed to `operator*`.  It's only if the parameter is a non-const reference (`T&` instead of `const T&`) that it cannot bind to a temporary.